# Hibernate Search Analyzer for Sort

Tags: hibernate-search

On Hibernate Search 5.3, and I've been attempting to build an analyzer that is suitable for sorting a number of our fields indexed through Hibernate Search.  I understand that for sorting one should not analyze the field, but as long as your analyzer returns a single token I believe it is no problem, plus then you can use some of the prebuilt filters to  case insensitivity, HTML stripping, and in my case, I'd like to also only sort by the first 20 characters.

So, something like this seems like it would work.

```
@AnalyzerDef(name = "sortAnalyzer", 
    tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = KeywordTokenizerFactory.class) ,        
    charFilters = { @CharFilterDef(factory = HTMLStripCharFilterFactory.class) },
    filters = 
            { 
                @TokenFilterDef(
                        factory = EdgeNGramFilterFactory.class,
                        params = {
                          @Parameter(name = "minGramSize",value = "20"),
                          @Parameter(name = "maxGramSize",value = "20")
                        }
                    ),                  
                @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
                @TokenFilterDef(factory = TrimFilterFactory.class)
            }
        ),
```

But it only works if I remove the EdgeNGramFilterFactory.  I suppose I could then just make a bridge to do the substring.  Then again, I could use a bridge to do the entire thing and set Analyze.NO.  My question is what is recommended?  Are there any advantages to a bridge vs. an analyzer?

And any reason the analyzer I'm trying to use doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An EdgeNGramFilterFactory will create several tokens so that would violate the principle of "single token". So that's why it doesn't work.

Generally when needing to apply tokenization and also sorting on a property, the solution is to index the property as multiple fields.

See the `@Fields` annotation:

```
@Fields({
   @Field(name="sortable_something",analyzer=@Analyzer(definition="sortable_html_key")),
   @Field(name="something",analyzer=@Analyzer(definition="html_ngrams_key"))
})
public String getSomething() {
```

Comment: Thanks @Sanne - I think my idea was to abuse the `EdgeNGramFilterFactory` as a substring, since I told it to only give me 20 chars min and max, there would only be one possible token working from the left, and that would be the first 20 chars.  But, in any case, I've decided to go with a bridge to do the substring, and the analyzer to do the rest.